# Two-way binding not working on custom DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've been trying to create a solution for a custom DataGrid column that can display an array of values. The one-way binding works for the solution I have below, but the two-way binding doesn't update the source. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

DataGridBoundTemplateColumn.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CustomColumnDemo
{
    public class DataGridBoundTemplateColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
    {
        public DataTemplate CellTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate CellEditingTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) => Generate(dataItem, CellTemplate);
        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) => Generate(dataItem, CellEditingTemplate);

        private FrameworkElement Generate(object dataItem, DataTemplate template)
        {
            var contentControl = new ContentControl { ContentTemplate = template, Content = dataItem };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentControl, ContentControl.ContentProperty, Binding);
            return contentControl;
        }
    }
}
```

DataGridArrayColumn.xaml:

```
<local:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn
    x:Class="CustomColumnDemo.DataGridArrayColumn"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomColumnDemo">
    <local:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
    </local:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</local:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn>
```

DataGridArrayColumn.xaml.cs:

```
namespace CustomColumnDemo
{
    public partial class DataGridArrayColumn : DataGridBoundTemplateColumn
    {
        public DataGridArrayColumn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't bind two-way to `.`, only to a property of `.`. Also, binding `ItemsSource` two-way is pointless, because there is no case where an ItemsControl or subclass will ever pass a new collection back to the viewmodel. `UpdateSourceTrigger` is equally pointless on a binding that is unable to update the source.

Comment: Thanks @EdPlunkett you make very good points. I wasn't aware of not being able to two-way bind to `.`. Do you have any suggestions of a neat way around this?